# Increment all keys and values in a dictionary in swift

Tags: swift

I want to increase each key and value in this dictionary by 0.5

```
var times = [0800.0:0855.0,0900.0:0939.0,0942.0:1021.0,1023.0:1054.0,1057.0:1136.0]
```

Comment: Create a new empty dictionary. Use `for key,val in times {` to get each `key` and `value`.  Add `0.5` to each and add the new key and value to the new dictionary.

Comment: Thanks although is there any way to do edit the old key,val pairs without having to re create a new dictionary

Comment: A dictionary where you are going to "increment the keys" should not be a dictionary. Think up a better data model before going any further. For example perhaps this would be better as an array of tuples, or an array of some custom struct.

Comment: You can edit the value (replace it), but you can't edit the key.  You can only add an item at the new key, and delete the old one.  That can be problematic if your key + 0.5 causes you to overwrite an old key.  It is bad practice to change something you are iterating over. It is best to create a new dictionary.

Comment: Ok, i didn't realize that you're not supposed to edit the keys. It makes sense now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you to formulate a more elaborated question the next time.

What did you tried?. Where did you get stuck?.

A good startpoint is [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Having said that, and asking what *I think* was your question:

The naive way of doing it is by iterating over the values and keys, increment the value/key and then remove the previous key:

```
for (k, v) in times {
    times[k + 0.5] = v + 0.5
    times[k] = nil
}
```

The problem with this approach is that if k + 0.5 exists in the dictionary at any point, the value will be overwritten.

### Option B

```
var newTimes = [Double: Double]()
for (k, v) in times {
    newTimes[k + 0.5] = v + 0.5
}
times = newTimes
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the thorough response. Option B seems to be a good fit for what I need. And yea, i'll be more specific next time. This was my first question in my two years of using stack overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request better than how you put it, you are using the wrong data structure. You have a list of time *ranges*, not values of time associated to other values of time.

So, my suggestion is that first of all, instead of `[Double: Double]` you use a `[ClosedInterval<Double>]`. It's also cooler to define it, like `let times = [0800.0 ... 0855.0, 0900.0 ... 0939.0]`.

Then, from there, it's quite easy to do what you requested:
`let shiftedTimes = times.map { ($0.start + 0.5) ... ($0.end + 0.5) }`

n.b.: The thing here is, *always find the most suited data structure to the data*. And *most suited* isn't *the one I know better*, but the one that represents it better.

### EDIT

By improving on the solution, I'd say that the preferred type would be `[ClosedInterval<NSTimeInterval>]`, that you can define operators like this:

```
func +<T: IntegerArithmeticType>(lhs: ClosedInterval<T>, rhs: T) -> ClosedInterval<T> {
    return (lhs.start + rhs) ... (lhs.end + rhs)
}
func +<S: Strideable, T where S.Stride == T>(lhs: ClosedInterval<S>, rhs: T) -> ClosedInterval<S> {
    return (lhs.start + rhs) ... (lhs.end + rhs)
}
```

and then the whole operation becomes `let shiftedTimes = times.map { $0 + 0.5 }` :)

Comment: That's an interesting way of solving this. I'll have to look into closed intervals a bit more.

Comment: It's a _more Swift_ way of doing it. Also, you can overload `+` to `IntervalType` and make it add to both bounds, but you always have to be careful with operators since they live in the global scope.

Comment: Also, I used `Double` because I was unsure but `NSTimeInterval` might be a better choice of type (which is simply a `typealias` for it)